# Junction tables - how to find out ID to add?

Tags: sql, sql-server, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to code an application in Microsoft Blazor with a SQL Server Database.
In this part of the application I want the user to select pictures and add them to a collection that he creates with a new name.

There are three tables, for now each with two columns:

- PictureID - PictureName
- CollectionID - CollectionName
- PictureID - CollectionID

PictureID and CollectionID in the first two tables are auto increment.

When the user adds a new collection with a new name and some selected pictures, I have the following information: PictureID, CollectionName.

**My Problem:** how do I get the ID of the newly added Collection, so I can add it to the junction table?

Do I really have to start a new query in the CollectionTable? And what should I search with the query - the highest ID? Not sure, if the newest is always the highest, if there were some deletions in the table. Seems to me, that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Have a look at the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: 1.Select CollectionName to get its CollectionID if it already exists.  2. If not existing, Insert CollectionName and output its CollectionID (as per Larnu).  3.  Insert junction table with its values.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the `name`s to look up the ids:

```
insert into junction (collectionid, pictureid)
    select c.collectionid, p.pictureid
    from collections c cross join
         pictures p
    where c.collectionname = @cname and p.picturename = @pname;
```